# What should be the architecture of portlet based project in liferay?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6, portal

I am going to developed project using liferay, since i haven't more experiences with it i need some expert advice on project architecture.

i am creating project with different portlet with diff functionality shall i create service builder (= DB persistence and business logic) common for all the portlets and use this service in all the portlets or it should be portlet specific?

also i would like to have web service which will use DB service of all portlet.

can anybody suggest me what should be the best way to develop such kind of project.

Thx in advanced

Answer (score 0):

If the entities you are going to create are required to access earch other, then it would be wise to use it in one project with one service.xml defining different entities. For using web services, be sure to create the required class by letting the Liferay's service builder know of it. (but setting remote-service="true" for the specific entity)

Comment: thanks for the answer. additional information on my question, should we create a different portlet project per section or we should combine all section in single portlet project? we have a different section like "Campaign","Advertise" etc now each section is interconnected, i mean to say in i would be able to display list of advertise mapped with particular portlet. can please guide me?

Comment: Could you post a different question for other things you want to know.